# CMIS PermissionDeniedException

Tags: python, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I'm trying to get service(SAP mobile document) via CMIS.

In service web client i can create folder and add file.

Via CMIS I can auth and get repo's list, but that's all. 
For other methods I get `cmislib.exceptions.PermissionDeniedException: Error 403`

I used this doca http://chemistry.apache.org/python/docs/

```
from cmislib import *

client = CmisClient('https://service/mcm/b/atom', 'user', 'pwd')
print client.getRepositories()

#REPO
#repo = client.defaultRepository
repo = client.getRepository('573f7fc4-2c76-49a2-b63c-d39e370edfde')
print repo.name

#FOLDER
rFolder = repo.rootFolder
print rFolder.id

#denied
#rFolder.getChildren()
#acl = rFolder.getACL()
#print rFolder.getName()
#newFolder = rFolder.createFolder('testfolder')
```

denied returns

`cmislib.exceptions.PermissionDeniedException: Error 403 at https://url/mcm/b/atom/573f7fc4-2c76-49a2-b63c-d39e370edfde/id?id=906f3ae3-a4c9-3210-7292-c840e0cff769&filter=&includeAllowableActions=false&includeACL=false&includePolicyIds=false&includeRelationships=&renditionFilter=`

*the same error for default repo

`#repo = client.defaultRepository`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP Mobile Documents requires cookies. Turn cookies on on the client side and those exceptions will disappear.

See http://help.sap.com/saphelp_mdocs10/helpdata/en/0e/432781e0c646a09602a4aab786734d/content.htm?frameset=/en/d5/476115e8264a33a52fd59d260892cb/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/69/ec44f07b34409a8b65005f51315f1a/plain.htm&node_id=105 how to the authentication works.

Comment: Thanks, and you've discussed, that cookies are not natively supported by the library
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-1005

Comment: What client can i choose instead Chemistry?

Comment: containing required functionality

Comment: I've started a Python library for SAP Mobile Documents but never finished it: https://github.com/fmui/sap-doccenter-experiments